# maximum and minimum of the function $ y=2 \sin3x+\sin 6x$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find maximum and minimum of the function
$$ y=2 \sin3x+\sin 6x$$

$y'= (\cos3x+\cos6x)= 6 \cos 3x (1+2 \sin 3x)=0 \Rightarrow \cos3x=0  \lor \sin3x=- \frac{1}{2}  \Rightarrow 3x= \frac{\pi}{2} \lor 3x= \frac{3\pi}{2} \lor 3x= \frac{7\pi}{6}\lor 3x= \frac{11\pi}{6}$.
Analyzing the sign of the derivative we can say that in $[0,2\pi]$:

$y'>0 \Rightarrow 0< 3x< \frac{\pi}{2} \lor \frac{7}{6} \pi<3x < \frac{3}{2}\pi \lor \frac{11}{6} \pi<3x <2 \pi $.

For $3x= \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $3x= \frac{3}{2} \pi$ there are two maxima.

For $3x= \frac{7}{6}\pi$ and $3x=  \frac{11}{6}\pi$ there are two maxima.

The first two positions can be summarized in $3x= \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \Rightarrow x= \frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{k \pi}{3}= \frac{\pi+2k \pi}{6}= \frac {1+2k}{6} \pi$.

The other two disequalities can be summarized in $3x= \frac{\pi}{2}+ \frac{2 \pi}{3} k \Rightarrow x=  \frac{\pi}{6}+ \frac{2 \pi}{9} k $.

Is it correct or I am missing something?

I don't understand my book shows a different solution.

Comment: $y = 2 \sin3x + \sin 6x = 2 \sin3x \, (1 + \cos 3x)$. For $x = \pi/12$, $y \approx 2.414 \gt 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function and its derivative are periodic, with period $\frac{2\pi}3$, so it  suffices to see what happens on an interval of length $\frac{2\pi}3$. Further more, the function is odd, and its derivative is even, so the interval $\bigl[0,\frac{\pi}3\bigr]$ will do.

Now, since $f'(x)=6(\cos 3x+\cos 6x)=6(2\cos^2 6x+\cos 6x -1)$, set $u=\cos 6x$. We have  $f'(x)=2u^2+u-1$,  and the roots of this quadratic polynomial are $u=-1,\frac12$. As $u$ is a cosine, we see  that, on the chosen interval, taking into account that $\cos 3x$ is decreasing,
\begin{align}
f'(x)=2u^2+u-1\ge 0\iff \frac12\le u\le 1&\iff \cos \frac\pi3\le\cos 3x\le \cos 0\\&\iff 0\le x\le\frac\pi 9\\
f'(x)=2u^2+u-1\le 0\iff -1\le u\le \frac12&\iff \cos\pi\le\cos 3x\le \cos \frac\pi3\\&\iff\frac\pi 9\le x\le \frac\pi 3.
\end{align}
Therefore the maxima are attained at $x\equiv\frac\pi 9\mod\frac{2\pi}3$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'= 6(\cos3x+\cos6x)= 6 \cos 3x (1+2 \sin 3x)$$

This is simply not true. You are implying that:

$$\cos6x=2\cos3x\sin3x$$

..which is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your calculation of $y'$. The derivative of $$2\sin 3x + \sin 6x$$ is
$$6\cos 3x + 6\cos 6x.$$